# Haar mesure on $\mathrm{GL}_{d}(F)$

Tags: nt.number-theory, harmonic-analysis, topological-groups, local-fields, haar-measure

$\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}$Let $F$ be a $\mathfrak{p}$-adic field and $\mathscr{O}_{F}$ its valuation ring. For any measurable subset of $M_{d}(F)$ such as
$$
A=
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
a_{11}+t^{\alpha_{11}}\mathscr{O}_{F} & \cdots & a_{1d}+t^{\alpha_{1d}}\mathscr{O}_{F} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
a_{d1}+t^{\alpha_{d1}}\mathscr{O}_{F} & \cdots & a_{dd}+t^{\alpha_{dd}}\mathscr{O}_{F}
\end{array} \right),
$$ we define $\mu_{M_{d}(F)}(A)=(\frac{1}{q})^{\sum_{i, j}\alpha_{ij}}$, where $t$ is an uniformizer of $F$ and $q$ is the order of residue field of $F$.
It is well-known that $\mu_{M_{d}(F)}$ is invariant for additive, that is, for any $a\in M_{d}(F)$,  $\mu_{M_{d}(F)}(a+A)=\mu_{M_{d}(F)}(A)$.

I want to know a relation between $\mu_{M_{d}(F)}$ and a left (or right) Haar measure on $\GL_{d}(F)$. Let $\mu$ be the left Haar measure on $\GL_{d}(F)$ such that $\mu(\GL_{d}(\mathscr{O}))=1$. The measurable subset $A$ on $M_{d}(F)$ as above, when $A\subset \GL_{d}(F),$ what is the relationship between the value of $\mu(A)$ and $\mu_{M_{d}(F)}(A)$ ?

Comment: Isn't it just the standard for writing the multiplicative Haar measure from the additive one? See my next comment. I vote to close!

Comment: $d\mu (x) = \alpha |\det (x)|^{-d} d \mu_{M_d} (x)$. Find the constant $\alpha$, then integrate.

Comment: "Standard" often means "the thing that everyone in my area of math knows". Instead of closing, just leave a nice answer!